# the variable is set to false inside my method, once the method runs it should change to True. But it does not

Tags: python, variables, boolean

```py
def checkPassword (password):
    
    upper = False
    lower = False
    number = False
    special = False
    
    for i in range (len(password)):
        if ((ord(password[i]) >= 65) and (ord(password[i]) <= 90)):
            upper = True    
        elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 97) and (ord(password[i]) <= 122)):
            lower = True    
        elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 0) and (ord(password[i]) <= 9)):
            number = True   
        elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 0) and (ord(password[i]) <= 9)) :
            special = True
            
    
    if ((upper == True) and (lower == True) and (number == True) and (special == True)):
        print ("Your password is strong")
    else:
        print ("Your password is not strong. Make sure to make it a mix between upper and lower case letters, number, and special characters.")

def main():
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    checkPassword (password)
```

Input:

```
running99*FAST
```

Output:

```
Your password is not strong. Make sure to make it a mix between upper and lower case letters, number, and special characters.
```

Problem: This password should come back as a strong password but it does not. I honestly don't know what I did wrong.

P.S. I am using the ASCII table to identify whether the letters are lowercase, uppercase, or numbers, and special characters.

Comment: Check how python outputs ord("0") and ord("9"), and then the same for a few of the symbols

Answer (score 1):

Your number and special check did not work. So I used `isdigit()`instead for number. Also, what is a special character? If a special character is something else than lower/upper character and number, then the `else` at the end should be fine.

```
upper = False
lower = False
number = False
special = False

password = "running99*FAST"

for i in range (len(password)):
    if ((ord(password[i]) >= 65) and (ord(password[i]) <= 90)):
        upper = True    
    elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 97) and (ord(password[i]) <= 122)):
        lower = True    
    elif password[i].isdigit():
        number = True   
    else:
        special = True
        
print (upper,lower,number,special)
if ((upper == True) and (lower == True) and (number == True) and (special == True)):
    print ("Your password is strong")
else:
    print ("Your password is not strong. Make sure to make it a mix between upper and lower case letters, number, and special characters.")
```

Output:

```
True True True True
Your password is strong
```

For a regex version:

```
import re

password = "running99*FAST"

def check(password):
    for test in [('lower','[a-z]'),('upper','[A-Z]'),('number','[0-9]'),('special','[^A-Za-z0-9]')]:
        if len(re.sub(test[1],"",password)) == len(password):
            return False, test[0]
    else: return True

print (check(password))
```

This code will return False if length after regex replace is equal to length before the replace (meaning type of characters absent). One violation returned at time.

And the oneliner which reports multiple violations:

```
import re

password = "runnFAST"

def check(password):
    return [(False, t[0]) if len(re.sub(t[1],"",password)) == len(password) else (True, t[0]) for t in [('lower','[a-z]'),('upper','[A-Z]'),('number','[0-9]'),('special','[^A-Za-z0-9]')]]

print (check(password))
```

Output:

```
[(True, 'lower'), (True, 'upper'), (False, 'number'), (False, 'special')]
```

Comment: Nice.  It would be great `enhancement` to point out `multiple` violations of the rules. For example, if password is `runningFast` -> (False, number, special). (for the `re` version)

Comment: That was a good opportunity for a oneliner then ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should be looking at what `ord()` is returning for each character (hint, look at what it should return for 0-9). The easiest way to do this is with a `print(ord(password[i]))` at the beginning of every loop step.

Also,

```
elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 0) and (ord(password[i]) <= 9)):
  number = True   
elif ((ord(password[i]) >= 0) and (ord(password[i]) <= 9)):
  special = True
```

you don't need this comparison twice. You can just set `number` and `special` True for the same condition if that is the logic you are going for.

Finally, you should consider not using `ord()` at all in place of other ways to tell if a char is uppercase, lowercase, or a number.